# Somewhere, somewhat, somehow, some...day?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, compounds, when, who

While talking to myself the other day, I noticed something odd.

We have the five W words and the H:

- What
- When
- Where
- Who
- Why
- How

I've heard three of these words said with "some" at the start:

- Somewhat
- Somewhere
- Somehow

But I've never heard "somewhen", "somewho" or "somewhy". If when, why, and who, are the same type of speech as what, where, and how, why don't we put "some" before the former three?

Comment: Maybe you're expecting more patterns than exit.

Comment: That may be a duplicate of the question, but there's no useful answer there.

Comment: LIke most _Why_ questions about language, a complete answer is "because that is how it is". You can sometimes speculate, or even demonstrate _how_ it came to be, but there is no answer to _why_ it came to be.

Comment: *somewhen: sometime; somewho: somebody; somewhy: ???*

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe *somewhy: for some reason*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good observations. A few additions ...

First, they're ***Wh***-words, not just *W*-words. The *wh* part goes back to Proto-Indo-European relative/interrogative root [****kʷo-***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=k%CA%B7o-) and shows up in Latin as well as in all the *qu*-words and -phrases we've borrowed, like *quantity, quality,* and *question*.

Second, you missed a few. As well as *who, what, where, when, why* and *how*, there's also *which* and *whether*. Not to mention old [paradigmatic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.pdf) variants like *whence* and *whither*, which are pretty rare in use these days.

Third, *some* is not the only word they can occur with. Consider *any*, which alternates with *some* in many contexts:

- *Did you see some people there? ~ Did you see any people there?*

So besides *somewhere, somehow,* and *somewhat*, there's also *anywhere* and *anyhow*. And then there's *everywhere* and *elsewhere*. It looks like locatives have the most fun, since *where* combines with the most words. Combinations like **somewhen*, **anywhat,* **elsewho,* and **everyhow* -- while understandable -- just don't exist in English.

Comment: I can attest *somewhen* attests in English sci-fi (and sappy country music).

Comment: American SF, too. It's unavoidable when you're dealing with imaginary dimensions.

Comment: I meant English as in the language, not the stoic people from that weird little island. I'm American.